# Get a specific amount of rows from SQL query

Tags: sql, numbers, return, rows

For a webshop I'm creating, I only need a specific amount of rows from a SQL query.
Like I would like to have 5 rows returned so I can loop those 5 with a foreach loop.

```
SELECT id, name from article
```

What do I have to add to my query to return a specific amount of rows?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @StijnDeSmet: w3schools is full of errors, please don't link to that site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TOP n` after `SELECT` to get the top n rows based on your criteria like so:

```
SELECT TOP 5 id, name from article
```

However, be sure to order your dataset because `TOP` in itself won't sort on a field you want.

EDIT: This is for T-SQL on SQL Server. I believe MySQL has a `LIMIT` keyword which functions in a similar way.

Comment: Those are just the top rows, might be that he wants to filter till 5 rows. Anyhow, OP should specify this :-)

Comment: Yep exactly. That's also why I mentioned it will get the top n rows only :)

Comment: That worked. It didn't really matter which rows were returned, only that 5 would be returned. Gonna accept as an anwer in a few minutes

Comment: Glad to be of help. Do remember though that there will be situations where it will matter which 5 are returned, and you need to look at other ways of restricting results.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE condition LIMIT number_of_rows;